# Select2 and floating divs issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-float, jquery-select2

If have a number of select2 select boxes that are all floating left on a screen.  When a large enough value is selected in one that it causes the box to resize, all select2 boxes floating underneath it are moved to the right of the box.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4upp3/1/) of the issue.

If boxes a-f are all on the same line, resize it until boxes d, e, and f is on the next line.  Once that happens, select either option in box b and watch what happens to boxes d, e, and f.  Is there a way to get the d to stay where it was?

If you resize the window such that there are only two boxes per row and then pick an option in box b, it reacts in a more desirable fashion.  But if you choose an option in box a, it messed up again.

If you resize the window such that only box f is on the second row, then selecting an option in a or e leads to an okay move for box f, but selecting options in boxes b, c, and d cause box f to move silly once again.

I've thought about just making the divs the boxes are in larger, but this does work because the boxes I'm using a multi selects with a large number of options (the reason I used select2 to begin with was the sheer number of options), which means that a user could still pick 2 or 3 values and encounter the same problem.

Another attempt I've tried is to get all of the divs to resize to the size of the largest div.  The problem is that there seems to be no standard implementation currently that would allow me to 'listen' for the resize and react.  Polling the sizes at some small interval and reacting if there is a change seems a very messy solution.

So, is there any way to get the lower level boxes to just move down when the select box fills up?

Here is the code from the jsfiddle:

```
HTML:
<div class="float">
    <select id="a" multiple="multiple" class="short">
        <option>This is going to be a really long value.</option>
        <option>This is going to be another really long value.</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="float">
    <select id="b" multiple="multiple" class="short">
        <option>This is going to be a really long value.</option>
        <option>This is going to be another really long value.</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="float">
    <select id="c" multiple="multiple" class="short">
        <option>This is going to be a really long value.</option>
        <option>This is going to be another really long value.</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="float">
    <select id="d" multiple="multiple" class="short">
        <option>This is going to be a really long value.</option>
        <option>This is going to be another really long value.</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="float">
    <select id="e" multiple="multiple" class="short">
        <option>This is going to be a really long value.</option>
        <option>This is going to be another really long value.</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="float">
    <select id="f" multiple="multiple" class="short">
        <option>This is going to be a really long value.</option>
        <option>This is going to be another really long value.</option>
    </select>
</div>




Javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#a').select2({
        width: 100,
        placeholder: 'a'
    });
    $('#b').select2({
        width: 100,
        placeholder: 'b'
    });
    $('#c').select2({
        width: 100,
        placeholder: 'c'
    });
    $('#d').select2({
        width: 100,
        placeholder: 'd'
    });
    $('#e').select2({
        width: 100,
        placeholder: 'e'
    });
    $('#f').select2({
        width: 100,
        placeholder: 'f'
    });
});


CSS
.float{
    float: left;
}

.short{
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: If you don't float them at all, and just let them be display:inline-block ( like they are by default ), they will behave better. http://jsfiddle.net/4upp3/3/

Comment: I couldn't just get rid of the divs, but by explicitly putting display:inline-block they started behaving better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as `mfreitas` mentioned, `inline-block` will cause them to line up the way you'd like.

When applying `inline-block`, the inside of the block is formatted as block-level box.  The element itself is formatted as an inline-level box.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late for the answer but if anyone search for this, give a chance to `z-index` for example `.select2-container { z-index: 1; }` or anything else grater than zero